# Image not getting displayed/update in QLabel using SIGNAL-SLOT in ROS node

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt-creator, ros

I am implementing the Qt code in ROS node. I have  a header file in which i have defined all the members, Q_SIGNAL and Q_SLOTS. In my .cpp file i want to display an image when i press a button(assignButton). But when i press the button, nothing shows up.

To test whether the connect function is working properly or not, i tried to display an image in the imageLabel which is stored in my laptop..and it worked.

**PROBLEM:-** I am taking the images from simulator in ROS through the 
`void SelectionInterface::imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)`  and i want to display those images in imageLabel by SIGNAL-SLOT..but its not getting displayed..no error

My code is following:-

**1. Header file-- SelectionInterface.h**

```
class SelectionInterface : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SelectionInterface(ros::NodeHandle *nh, RosThread *rt, QMainWindow *parent =       0);
    ~SelectionInterface();

private:
    RosThread *rosThread;
    ros::NodeHandle *nodeHandle;

    // ROS Subscribers
    image_transport::Subscriber image_sub;
    void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg);




    // More Memberfunctions and Variables
    QWidget *newCentralWidget;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
    QPushButton *assignButton;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
    QLabel *imageLabel;

    QImage image;

    // ...

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

Q_SIGNALS:
    void windowClosedSignal();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void quitInterface();
    void assignImage();//QImage
};
```

**2. .cpp file**

```
#include "SelectionInterface.h"
#include <iostream>

SelectionInterface::SelectionInterface(ros::NodeHandle *nh, RosThread *rt, QMainWindow         *parent): QMainWindow (parent)
{
    rosThread = rt;
nodeHandle = nh;

// Subscribing and Publishing
image_transport::ImageTransport it(*nh);

// Setup user interface here
newCentralWidget = new QWidget;

quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit"); 
assignButton = new QPushButton("Assign Image"); 
layout = new QVBoxLayout;
imageLabel = new QLabel;
imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);


layout->addWidget(imageLabel);
layout->addWidget(quitButton);
layout->addWidget(assignButton);
newCentralWidget->setLayout(layout);

this->setCentralWidget(newCentralWidget);

// Signal-Slot Connections

connect(this, SIGNAL(windowClosedSignal()), this, SLOT(quitInterface()));
connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
connect(assignButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(assignImage()));
// ...
}


void SelectionInterface::imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{

QImage image(&(msg->data[0]), msg->width, msg->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);  
}

SelectionInterface::~SelectionInterface()
{
//destructer (leave empty)
}

void SelectionInterface::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
Q_EMIT windowClosedSignal();
}

void SelectionInterface::quitInterface()
{
rosThread->stop();
rosThread->wait();

std::cout << "Good bye.\n";
}

void SelectionInterface::assignImage()
{      
        imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));       
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to your problem? I am facing an apparently similar issue now...

Comment: @Beginner: The problem was solved but I am really very sorry that now I have forgotten how did I solve it. I think that the answer below helped me but I am not sure about it. Sorry...good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt QImage can replace `~` to your home path. Try to specify full path e.g. '/home/user/Pictures/wallpapers/buddha.jpg'.

Comment: OK, here comes another guess.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But now i have changed my post to my original problem. Actually the source of image in my program is the function `void SelectionInterface::imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)`. And then i want to put this image into the imageLabel in the **assignImage()**